# How to change custom font text size?

Tags: java, javafx, fonts

I've uploaded my own font in eclipse like this:

```
Font buttonFontDefault = Font.loadFont(MenuView.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/font/niagra_eng.TTF"), 100);
```

And it works just fine. The only problem I have, is that the only way of changing the text size, of buttons and labels written with this font, is to make a new font where the only difference is the size in the end of the code.
I also tried the following:

```
button.setScaleX(0.50);
button.setScaleY(0.50);
```

The code above works, but then it ruins my GridPane layout, because the gridpane acts according to the original button size.
I'd rather have a solution without any use of css, but if that's not a possibility then I guess I have no other choice. But why shouldn't there be a solution without css?

I haven't been able to find any help in the internet so far. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only way to change the font size of a custom font is to create another instance of Font class by calling `Font.loadFont(String name, double size)`.

Comment: To keep the grid pane's layout working with scaled buttons, wrap the button in a `Group` and add the `Group` to the grid pane, instead of adding the button directly to the grid pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle the fonts programmatically you can do it like @ItachiUchiha suggested by defining the font size when loading the font:

```
Font.loadFont(String name, double size)
```

The drawback of this method - as well as handling it programmatically at all - is that for each font size you will require a font instance handled by your code.

A cleaner solution in my opinion is to handle the fonts through CSS. Starting with Java 8, the font families can be defined through CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('Roboto-Medium.ttf');
}

.text {
    -fx-font-family: "Roboto";
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
}
```

For a detailed example, check out this [post](http://www.guigarage.com/2014/10/integrate-custom-fonts-javafx-application-using-css/)